# Nginx refuses ssh, locked outside

Tags: azure, nginx, networking, deployment

I deployed a ubuntu VM in the Azure microsoft cloud. I might have forgotten to allow ssh connections when I set up the firewall. So now whenever I try to ssh in my VM I get a ssh timeout. I checked using nmap and see that only the http and https ports are open. Is there any way to reconfigure the firewall so I can allow ssh. Note its not azure thats blocking the ssh connection, its my nginx server itself. I set nginx to auto restart when restarting the VM so that won't be a solution.

In the worst case I would just delete the VM and make a new one, but this would mean I have to reinstall everything.
thx for helping

Edit I will just make a new VM.

Comment: Have you tried checking the logs? They can be found in `/var/log/nginx`

Comment: How would I be able to check the logs if I cannot ssh in to the VM ? @ Nickson Thanda

Comment: How did you set up the nginx config? Can you change it without SSHing into the VM?

Comment: My nginx has two routes, one to a express backend, the other to my react frontend, so I cannot ssh in to the vm, because of the firewall , not realy because of nginx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a panel inside the azure portal where you can execute a remote command. I used this to execute `sudo ufw allow ssh`, now I can connect back to the vm!

Answer (score 0):

Since the `Run command` option might not be available for your resource group and for your access rights, another possibility is to use *Azure CLI* command-line tool: if you have it [installed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/install-azure-cli), you need to log in via `az login`, and then you need to type:

```sh
az vm run-command invoke -g YourResourceGroup \
 -n YourVM_Name --command-id RunShellScript \
--scripts "sudo ufw allow ssh"
```